How to use xslt transform xml creating new tags from the value in other tags
Please can someone help me use xsl transform xml to xml and original xml first element value to new tag name.
original [xml]:
<Workbook>
 <Worksheet>
  <Row>
   <Data>Item</Data> <--convert to tag name
   <Data>Desc</Data> <--convert to tag name
   <Data>Tariff</Data> <--convert to tag name
   <Data>Qty</Data> <--convert to tag name
   <Data>UOM</Data> <--convert to tag name
  </Row>
  <Row>
   <Data>1</Data>
   <Data>SSD PCIe Gen 4x4 AGAMMIXS 70B-2T-CS G/XPG GAMMIXS70 B 2T CS</Data>
   <Data>85235100000</Data>
   <Data>50</Data>
   <Data>PCE</Data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
   <Data>2</Data>
   <Data>MODULE DDR5 AX5U5600C3616 G-DCLARBK ADATA OCDDR5U-D </Data>
   <Data>84733000006</Data>
   <Data>30</Data>
   <Data>NPR</Data>
  </Row>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>

To:
<Workbook>
  <Worksheet>
   <Row>
    <Item>1</Item>
    <Desc>SSD PCIe Gen 4x4 AGAMMIXS 70B-2T-CS G/XPG GAMMIXS70 B 2T CS</Desc>
    <Tariff>85235100000</Tariff>
    <Qty>50</Qty>
    <UOM>PCE</UOM>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Item>2</Item>
    <Data>MODULE DDR5 AX5U5600C3616 G-DCLARBK ADATA OCDDR5U-D </Data>
    <Tariff>84733000006</Tariff>
    <Qty>30</Qty>
    <UOM>NPR</UOM>
  </Row>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>

Can someone help me solve this problem ? Thanks a lot!!

Please show what you tried so far.

Hi Siebe Jongebloed Thank you, problem solved!.
